# Small SQL Database for logs?

Tags: sql, database, logging

Im thinking about to use a DB for my logs instead of a normal txt file. Why? In a DB I could handle them much more easier than with a txt file. Actually I dont have a big log txt, there are some exceptions, and for every single day: userlogins and what client uploaded what file where - but even here, a DB would make sense or? What free (for noncommercial and for commercial) small DBs should I try? I could use a "real" DB like PostgreSQL or nosql with a simple XML DB with BaseX, so that's what I thought. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Edit: Oh sry forgot - Im using .NET, but maybe that's not so importan.

Comment: What technology are you logging from?

Comment: "I'm thinking about replacing text files with XML" Java developer, I see.

Comment: Paddy: oh sry forgot its .NET, Panagiotis: SQLite is one option right, I just thought Postgre is more powerful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What will you do with your logging information? If you are going to do regular complex analysis work on it (performance, trending, etc.) then a database would be very useful. If you just need a place to dump "this happened" type messages that will be used infrequently at best (post-crash analysis and the like), a simple text or XML file should be more than sufficient. (If you do that, cycle the files ever day or week -- rename the current file, say with the date/time, and start a new "current" log file.)

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLite. Really small footprint, cross-platform, single file for the whole db and serverless (http://www.sqlite.org) Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Package Manager you can install **SqlServerCompact** which works within your solution.

Use the **Package Manager Console** and type the following command:

```
Install-Package SqlServerCompact
```